# Fire observable sequentially (or parallel) not working, when making http calls angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, rxjs

I've create an "array" of observables, and what to fire them sequentially (or parallel will also make the job).

```
let listObservables: Observable<any>[]=[];

  for(let index of this.listIndexImagesToDelete){


    let obserToAdd = this.httpImageService.deleteImageInProductIdFolderFromContainer_imagesWysiwygProduct(
      this.arrayImagesInWysiwyg[index].productIdFolder, this.arrayImagesInWysiwyg[index].guid);

    listObservables.push(obserToAdd);

  }


  Observable.from(listObservables)
    .subscribe(
      (data: any)=> {
        console.log("[zr]Image deleted.");
      },
      (e:any) => {
        console.log('onError: %s', e);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('onCompleted');
        this.http_GetAllImagesInWysiwyg();
      }
    );
```

The console log prints:

//(depending on the number of observables in the array, it will print more than once)

"[zr]Image deleted."
This code run with no exception but the api in the back end is never called. How come nothing happens even though the success message is printed ("[zr]Image deleted.")??

Comment: Track the API calls in Console, and verify the parameters you are passing in that call. If it is fine then check your Server code, might be there is some issues with your Server side code.

Comment: the api call works, I've also tested it just using a simple single observable call.

Comment: Try `from` like https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an array of Observables as an argument for:

```
Observable.concat(listObservables)
```

will not work, because (my version of RXJS 5.0.3) there is no override for passing an array, thus it should be done as:

```
Observable.concat(listObservables[0],listObservables[1],listObservables[n])
```

To overcome the issue we'll use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
That is the syntactic sugar(3 dots) ... for getting each array item as single item for an argument.

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2]; //from [0, 1, 2] to 0, 1, 2  
myFunction(...args);
```

Thus the working function call should be:

```
  Observable.concat(...listObservables) //<--**using SPREAD OPERATOR**
  .subscribe(
    (data: any)=> {
      console.log("[zr]Image deleted.");
      console.log("[zr]Image deleted. : data: ", data);

    },
    (e:any) => {
      console.log('onError: %s', e);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('onCompleted');
      this.http_GetAllImagesInWysiwyg();
    }
  );
```

My issue is mentioned in this article, dealing with other rxjs functions: ["Rx.Observable.merge is not accepting Array of Observables"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1308http://)

Answer (score 2):

Your Obervables are never subscribed, so the won't be fired.

- If you want to execute them sequential, you want to use `concat`:

```js
Observable
  .concat(listObservables)
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log("[zr]Image deleted.", data);
  },
  (e:any) => {
    console.log('onError: %s', e);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('onCompleted');
    this.http_GetAllImagesInWysiwyg();
  }
);
```

working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/uG5jVzcOMxC7OuE4HQU3?p=preview

- If you want to fire them all at once, use `forkJoin`:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

```js
Observable
   .forkJoin(listObservables)
   .subscribe(resultArray => // will contain all results from your listObservables
```

Will subscribe all Observables, "wait" until they are done and merge the results into a single Subscription.

Comment: Even tho your answer is good, I don't think it's what Luther wants. The title is "fire observables sequentially", `forkJoin` will run them in //

Comment: @mxii Your solution(forkJoin) works, even though they run in parallel, I can tweak the backend to handle it. Just for the record, why didn't my observables in my original code get fired?

Comment: @mixii I've tried using "concat()" but nothing happens, console doesn't event print "[zr]Image deleted.", as if the observables aren't subscribed. Only forkJoin() seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, missed one line: `.concatAll()`. See updated answer and plunker. Will now execute them sequential

Comment: @mxii I've added concatAll(). I get this error in the client/browser: ".Observable.concat(...).concatAll is not a function".

Comment: see my plunker: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatAll'`